# Shell Script-Checking if file exists, creating one, export terminal as log

Tags: bash, shell

I've just started learning bash yesterday and I need a little help. I need to make a script that will check if a file exists on co-workers computers and, if it doesn't the, script will make one. I have a general idea for that. The more important help I need is recording or logging the script to an output.txt or something of the sorts. I've seen the script command but it seems to be manual. I need it to record every interaction from the start to end and then export it and exit.

I could probably test if that log exists and then append whatever the script needs to check. I assume to start I could do file="./file" (example) and then do

```
    if [ -e "$file" ]; then whatever.
```

What I plan to do is make a script that maybe checks if a firewall is on or if the co-workers have some file and then export the result(s) to some dir (mkdir). Pure examples. I really just need assistance on the exporting of the whole terminal input and output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple script just check the existense of file, if so just move it to yourlocaiton dir.

```
#!/bin/sh
    if [ -f /etc/cruelworld.txt ] ; then
        echo "File exist and moving it to my dir"
        mv /etc/cruelworld.txt /yourlocation
    fi
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems straightforward enough. In your if statement is the /etc/... in the root? Like is the default starting point always the root? So I would just be more specific with the dir going through root/(somewhere)/(somewhere)/Documents for example.

Comment: And do you have any idea on how I'd export the whole terminal text after it goes through a script? I tried putting script -q output.txt at the beginning of it, however, it seemed to need input. Is there a better command for recording data/outputs?

Comment: its just an example, to check the existence of file.  well perhaps copying or moving from /etc dir it might ask you to be in sudo. You can create a file  in else stamenet if the file doesnt exist, just do touch "name_of_the_file"

Comment: Thanks, I got it working! I do have another question separate to this topic. I need to parse through a .log file (ex. more corecaptured.log) and I need to remove the timestamp (leave month and dom). Also, I need to only show one column of that .log file. I haven't used sed or awk before but I know I'll have to limit the digits with [0-9]{x}. Any ideas?

Comment: By that I mean if a log has Mar 22 02:28:00 data|data|data, how would I remove just the time. I want to leave Mar 22 and the FIRST data column

Comment: try to use cut or awk utility to remove columns and things you dont want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your script as :
 if [ -f file.txt ]; then echo "File found"; else touch file.txt; fi

Comment: Would I do that under/in the -e if statement or just have an if -f?

Comment: You can use -f if you want to check for the existence of a regular file. Otherwise, you can use -e for the existence of any type of file.